# What is the use of the event parameter/argument in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
###Python tkinter
def exit()
.
.
def exit(event)
.
.
def exit(event=None)
.
.

file_menu.add_command (label="Exit", image=exit_icon, compound=tk.LEFT, accelerator="Ctrl+e", command=exit)
```

Comment: ```def exit(event=None)``` means if no parameter is provided, then the default value of ```event``` is None. ```def exit(event)``` means a parameter *has* to be provided or it will raise an error as no default value is there. ```def exit()``` means no parameter is provided and the function can be directly called. Error is raised if a parameter is provided as there is no argument provided when function is defined

Comment: previously i used exit() only and it worked fine graphically on mouse click but when i bind this function with shortcut key ctrl+e then exit() did not worked...

Comment: ```bind()``` provided additional arguments but the function cannot take those as no parameters are provided during its definition. You can do ```def exit(*args)```

Comment: Most welcome. Happy to help

Comment: thankyou again so much

Answer (score 2):

When you use `bind` to find a function to an event, the bound function will be passed an object which represents the event that triggered the callback. If you want to call a function through a binding, that function needs to accept this object as an argument.

If you are calling the function from the `command` attribute of a button or menu, or just calling it directly from some other function, the function will *not* get an event object.

For the case where you want a function to be used both with `bind` and with `command`, you can make this parameter optional (assuming that your function doesn't actually use this object). That is what your third example does.

In your first example, `exit` is defined to accept no arguments so it cannot be directly bound to an event. The other two examples can be used directly in a `bind` statement since they accept the `event` parameter.

The first and third examples can be used from a `command` attribute since it does not require the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

When you `.bind()` an event to a widget, you automatically add a Object/Pointer to the [BindTable](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkLib/BindTable.html), in order to [associate a command with a sequence](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/bind.html#M4). When an event/sequence occurs then the associated object is parsed to the command that may contain one or more of the described [EventFields](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/event.html#M9). This is the reason you add the `event` parameter to your functions when you use it as *bounded command*.

If you want to use the same function as an ordinary function besides the event sequence it is bounded to, you can make the event argument optional/add a default value to the argument. This can be done by `event=None`, but be aware that there will be `None` associated with event and therefore none of the EventFields are available in those cases.