# tkinter: passing event arguments and additional arguments to an event handler function

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I would like to pass both *event* and an *additional* argument to a handler function.
The purpose of this is to display a context menu using the `x_root` and `y_root` arguments of the event object.

I have tried the two techniques shown below. For simplicity, I prefer the one that uses the lambda function, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to fix it? Any idea or explanation?

```
import tkinter as tk
    
class Example:

    def __init__(self, window):
        base = tk.Frame(window).pack()

        for i in range(3):
            l = tk.Label(base, text='label '+str(i))
            l.pack()

            def interhandler(event, self=self, i=i):
                return self._handler_one(event, i)

            l.bind("<Button-1>", interhandler)
            l.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, i=i: self._handler_two(i))

    def _handler_one(self, event, k):
        print(event) # works
        print('left click on label', k)

    def _handler_two(self, k):
        print(event) # does not work
        print('right click on label ', k)

main = tk.Tk()
example = Example(main)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you want to send both then `_handler_two` should get two values `def _handler_two(self, event, k):`

Comment: It does not work, because you just parse `i` and no `event`. `self._handler_two(event,i)` and  `def _handler_two(self, event, k): ` should work

Comment: @Thingamabobs, that's right! Yo can post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Thank you, but @furas was bit quicker.

Comment: By the way, it seems strange to me: I assumed that handler functions only take one argument...

Comment: An event driven function has no difference from an ordinary function, despite the fact that tkinter parses an event object through the interface. If you are interested, I have wrote something about [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742314/13629335) and the [event parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73433401/13629335)

Comment: Thanks, It will be usefull foro me!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send both values then function should get both values

```
def _handler_two(self, event, k):  # <--- event
    print(event)  # now it works
    print('right click on label ', k)
```

And you should send both values

```
lambda event, i=i: self._handler_two(event, i)  # <--- event
```

---

Full working code

```
import tkinter as tk
    
class Example:

    def __init__(self, window):
        base = tk.Frame(window).pack()

        for i in range(3):
            l = tk.Label(base, text='label '+str(i))
            l.pack()

            def interhandler(event, self=self, i=i):
                return self._handler_one(event, i)

            l.bind("<Button-1>", interhandler)
            l.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, i=i: self._handler_two(event, i))  # <--- event

    def _handler_one(self, event, k):
        print(event) # works
        print('left click on label', k)

    def _handler_two(self, event, k):  # <--- event
        print(event)  # now it works
        print('right click on label ', k)

main = tk.Tk()
example = Example(main)
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issues**: You have not passed the event argument when you invoke your `_handler_two` callback function. Your callback function should also take two arguments, the event and the additional value.

**Solution**: Your code with the corrections can be found below:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example:

    def __init__(self, window):
        base = tk.Frame(window).pack()

        for i in range(3):
            l = tk.Label(base, text='label ' + str(i))
            l.pack()

            def interhandler(event, self=self, i=i):
                return self._handler_one(event, i)

            l.bind("<Button-1>", interhandler)
            l.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, i=i: self._handler_two(event, i))

    def _handler_one(self, event, k):
        print(event)
        print('left click on label', k)

    def _handler_two(self, event, k):
        print(event)
        print('right click on label ', k)


main = tk.Tk()
example = Example(main)
main.mainloop()
```

**Sample Output**:  Below is the resulting window:

[image]

Below is the output after clicking the right mouse button on label 0:

```
<ButtonPress event state=Mod1 num=3 x=29 y=16>
right click on label  0
```

**Alternatively**: You can define your function to take a variable number of arguments:

```
def _handler_two(self, *args):
    print(args[0])
    print('right click on label ', args[1])
```