# reading entry values from function and using inside other function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a bot, which should scrape website. We have one fixed given URL link placeholder (as an Entry in tkinter) it works well.

Also, I have add button with help of it, user adds as many as button-clicked entry boxes.

When I click scrape, I cannot take the text values from that newly added entry boxes.

here is code;

```
ListOfEntries=[]

fixed_entry = ttk.Entry(canvas1, width=79)
fixed_entry.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.0125)
fixed_entry.focus()

text_entryNumbers=[]

def addurlbox():
    global extraentryBoxValue
    extraentryBox = tk.Entry(canvas1,width=63)
    extraentryBox.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.125 * (len(text_entryNumbers) + 1))
    text_entryNumbers.append(extraentryBox)
    extraentryBoxValue=extraentryBox

def crawler():
    entreeURL = fixed_entry.get()
    ListOfEntries.append(entreeURL)
    ListOfEntries.append(extraentryBoxValue.get())

    for i in range(len(ListOfEntries)):
        varUrl_SC = ListOfEntries[i]
```

I am able only to take fixed url entry value, and first added entry box value, I want to take values inside as many  entry boxes added and use them inside loop in another function

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=420, height=330)
canvas1.pack()

lbllst=[]

fixed_entry = ttk.Entry(canvas1, width=63)
fixed_entry.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.125)
#canvas1.create_window(100, 20, width=300,window=fixed_entry)
fixed_entry.focus()
lbllst.append(fixed_entry)

def crawler():

    xUrl='https://www.amazon.com/s?bbn=1&rh=n%3A1%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A8622846011&dc&qid=1666333032&rnid=8622845011&ref=lp_1_nr_p_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin_4'

    chrome_options=Options()
    chrome_options.headless=False
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1200')

    webdriver_service = Service(r'C:\pythonPro\w_crawl\AmznScrpBot\chromedriver.exe')

    driver=webdriver.Chrome(
    options=chrome_options,
    service=webdriver_service)
    driver.get(xUrl)

    javaScript = "window.scrollBy(0, 1000);"
    driver.execute_script(javaScript)

    driver.save_screenshot(r'C:\pythonPro\w_crawl\AmznScrpBot\hn_homepage.png')
    driver.quit()

def addurlbox():
    textentry = tk.Entry(canvas1,width=63)
    textentry.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.125 * (len(lbllst) + 1))
    lbllst.append(textentry)

def print_entry():
    if lbllst!='':
        for i in range(len(lbllst)):
            print(lbllst[i].get())

add_account_button = tk.Button(canvas1, text="print", font='Segoe 9', command=print_entry)
add_account_button.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.713)

add_urlbox_button = tk.Button(canvas1, text="Add another URL", font='Segoe 9', command=addurlbox)
add_urlbox_button.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.033)

button1 = tk.Button(text='scrape', command=crawler, bg='darkblue', fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(300, 250, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the issue ? What entry do you want to reference and where ? Your question isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions to your problem and it is not clear what you really try to achieve. To give some examples:

Get widget that has currently the focus:

```
import tkinter as tk

def example():
    print(root.focus_get())

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvasframe = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(2,2, anchor=tk.NW, window=canvasframe)
for i in range(10):
    entry = tk.Entry(canvasframe)
    entry.pack()
tk.Button(root, command=example, text='example').pack()
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But this might end up in a entirely different widgets, maybe one that neither has a `get` method. You could check if it is an instance of `tk.Entry` but you still could have clicked another `tk.Entry` before clicking your button.

You could forget about the `tk.Button` and bind a event to your return-key and get the widget by [the event parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73433401/13629335):

```
import tkinter as tk

def example(event):
    print(event.widget.get())

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvasframe = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(2,2, anchor=tk.NW, window=canvasframe)
for i in range(10):
    entry = tk.Entry(canvasframe)
    entry.pack()
    entry.bind('<Return>', example)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But if you insist to use a `tk.Button` you also could bind the event sequence `'<FocusIn>'` and have globally available path to that widget which you can use to find the widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

def example():
    widget = root.nametowidget(last_entry.get())
    print(widget.get())

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvasframe = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(2,2, anchor=tk.NW, window=canvasframe)
last_entry = tk.StringVar()
for i in range(10):
    entry = tk.Entry(canvasframe)
    entry.pack()
    entry.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e:last_entry.set(e.widget))
tk.Button(root, command=example, text='example').pack()
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But still, you could have missclicked to a different `tk.Entry` but at least it will be one you have intended to use.

Be aware there for sure more ways to achieve what you want, but it seems your own intention about what your code should do is not clear yet. Work your idea out first and then start coding, otherwise you end up writing code over and over again.

---

> I need to take all the values from all values of entry box, not
> depending how many of them are there. nd to use that values(url)
> inside crawler function

for ALL entries, you can use `winfo_children` and check if it is an instance of `tk.Entry`

```
def example():
    inputs = []
    for widget in canvasframe.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(widget, tk.Entry):
            inputs.append(widget.get())
    print(inputs)
```

Comment: @xlmaster I think I have answered just that. Do you want just the newest entry or what? In addition `place` seems not a good choice here, your application will look significantly different on other devices. I think just resizing the window should break your layout

Comment: @xlmaster updated. You still should think about another geometry manager and use `create_window` to have widgets in your canvas. Otherwise you are placing the widgets above the canvas, not into the canvas.

Comment: @xlmaster iterate over the entries in your canvas. I have added an example for it.