# tkinter creating buttons in a loop

Tags: loops, tkinter, button, lambda

I acknowledge there is a similar question here: [tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

But that does not solve my problem.

```
from tkinter import *

Master = Tk()
Master.geometry("1920x1080")
Master.configure(bg = "#000000")

img1C1C1C = PhotoImage(file = f"#1C1C1C.png")
img505050 = PhotoImage(file = f"#505050.png")

def Enter(Widget, event):
  if not event.state:
    Widget.configure(image = img505050)

def Leave(Widget, event):
  if not event.state:
    Widget.configure(image = img1C1C1C)

for Row in range(5):
  for Column in range(10):
    x = 25 + 125 * Column + 25 * Column
    y = 25 + 100 * Row + 25 * Row
    
    Widget = Button(master = Master, bg = "#000000", image = img1C1C1C, bd = 0, borderwidth = 0, activebackground = "#000000", relief = "flat", highlightthickness = 0)
    Widget.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: Enter(Widget, event))
    Widget.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: Leave(Widget, event))
    Widget.place(x = x, y = y, width = 125, height = 100)
```

Here I am creating a simple script to create some rows of buttons and columns of buttons.

However when I hover over any button the image change only applied to the last button created by the loop. I have tried long and hard to fix this an I cannot I need some help thanks.

Looking on Google
Coding in a different language like HTML, CSS and JS
Looking on StackOverflow
Looking on YouTube
I have even tried BING

Comment: Are you aware that you don' t have to pass the widget? The `event` that is passed in has a reference to the widget (ie: `event.widget`). Also, it's not clear why you don't think that other question applies. The highest voted answer is exactly what you need to do if you want to pass the widget anyway.

Comment: I tried doing lambda (str(Row) + str(Column)): ... and it did not work. I also tried adding the widgets to a matrix and that did not work

Comment: `lambda event, w=Widget: Enter(w, event)` would work. But as Bryan said, you don't need it. Look at [event parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356340/what-is-the-use-of-the-event-parameter-argument-in-tkinter/73433401#73433401) and [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742314/13629335) and may take a look at [event.state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72917102/13629335)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass `Widget` as part of the event handling. The callback is given an object that has a reference to the widget. You can write your callback and bindings like this:

```
def Enter(event):
  if not event.state:
    event.widget.configure(image = img505050)
...
Widget.bind("<Enter>", Enter)
```

If you really want to pass `Widget` to your existing callback even though the widget is part of the `event` object, you need to do what the question you pointed to recommends. It would look something like this:

```
Widget.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, widget=Widget: Enter(widget, event))
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```