# How do I use binding to change the position of an arc?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am having trouble setting the x position of an arc called "pac_man", and then changing it using += with a function called "xChange()".

I have tried multiple things, but I think using a dictionary would suffice. This is because the variable "coord" needs 4 values to assign shape and position for "pac_man."

```
#Imports
from tkinter import *


#Functions
def xChange():
  print("Change the value of pac_man's x position here")


#Object Attributes
wn = Tk()
wn.geometry('512x320')
wn.title('Moving with Keys')

cvs = Canvas(wn, bg='limegreen', height=320, width=512)

coord = {'x_pos': 10, 'y_pos': 10, 'x_size': 50, 'y_size': 50}

pac_man = cvs.create_arc(
  coord['x_pos'],
  coord['y_pos'],
  coord['x_size'],
  coord['y_size'],
  start=45,
  extent=270,
  fill='yellow',
  outline='black',
  width=4,
)

cvs.bind('<Right>', xChange)

cvs.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments in the code:

```
#Imports
from tkinter import *

#Functions
def move(event):#add event parameter
    pixels = 1 #local variable, amount of pixels to "move"
    direction = event.keysym #get keysym from event object
    if direction == 'Right':#if keysym is Left
        cvs.move('packman',+pixels, 0)
        #canvas has already a method for move, use it!
        #move "packman" +1 pixel on the x-axis and 0 on the y-axis

#Window
wn = Tk()
wn.geometry('512x320')
wn.title('Moving with Keys')
#Canvas
cvs = Canvas(wn, bg='limegreen', height=320, width=512, takefocus=True)
#coord = {'x_pos': 10, 'y_pos': 10, 'x_size': 50, 'y_size': 50}
#tkinter stores these values in form of a list
#You can retrieve it with like this print(cvs['coords'])
pac_man = cvs.create_arc(
    10,10,50,50,
    start=45,
    extent=270,
    fill='yellow',
    outline='black',
    width=4,
    tags=('packman',)#add a tag to access this item
    #tags are tuple^!!
    )
#cvs.bind('<Right>', xChange)
#You could bind to canvas but would've made sure
#that canvas has the keyboard focus
#it is easier to bind to the window
wn.bind('<Left>', move)
wn.bind('<Right>', move)
wn.bind('<Up>', move)
wn.bind('<Down>', move)
cvs.pack()
wn.mainloop()
```

Additional resource, in case you wonder.
[event parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68356340/13629335)

Comment: Thank you!
I had no idea that Canvas already had a method for moving, but I am not so sure I understand what "takefocus" and "tags" do, and where you put the "coord" dictonary. How does Canvas know where to put "pac_man"?

If you don't mind, could you answer these questions for me in more detail?

Comment: The `takefocus` is slipped through, I first wanted to show you how you would bind the canvas itself and what are the prerequisite for. But it would take more text to explain than I have added code to your script. You can read about [id's and tags](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.html#M16) on the official [tcl - canvas documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.html). If you have further minor questions, there is a [tkinter chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249491/tkinter) now on this site and I have permitted you *write-access* @henryCoding

Comment: Thank you for the help and opportunities. I really appreciate it!